# Tensorflow on jupyter notebook does not see my GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I just installed tensorflow-gpu with CUDA and cuDNN via the terminal and when I type :

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

I get :

```
 I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1660 Ti computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.59GHz coreCount: 24 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 268.26GiB/s
2021-06-17 14:04:01.816090: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-06-17 14:04:01.822415: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-06-17 14:04:01.822552: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-06-17 14:04:01.826370: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-06-17 14:04:01.828187: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-06-17 14:04:01.837986: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_11.dll
2021-06-17 14:04:01.840556: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-06-17 14:04:01.841009: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-06-17 14:04:01.841131: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

Now when I run the same command in a Jupyter Notebook cell I just get `[]`.

Do you know how to solve this problem ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make sure that your notebook is using the same python interpreter as your shell.

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: To answer above question .`Create a new environment with conda create -n  "env_name" python= 3.5 anaconda (just replace "env_name" with your desired environment name and 3.5 with version as your shell) ,Install tensorflow-gpu  in that environment.` and access Jupyter notebook ,